# how to load a page containing jQuery with ajax and keep the code functioning?

Tags: php, jquery

Hey everybody thanks for reading .

I have a problem i don't know how to keep functioning jquery code of a page that has been loaded with ajax. The problem is that on the original page the code executes so the jquery framework has already loaded and when the ajax call comes in to load the data of the other page i get unfunctioning jquery code. The jquery code that was loaded from the ajax page dose not work .

If i was not clear ask for clarification , for more detal the code is below :

The page into which i load the jquery pages :

```
<?php 
ob_start();
include 'includes/chk.php';


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#account_link').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "ajax/settings_account.php",
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#div_container_sett_acc').replaceWith('<div id="div_container_sett_acc" style="text-align: center;">'+msg+'</div>');

                }
            });
        });

      $('#settings_link').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                url: "ajax/settings_account.php",
                success: function(msg){
                    $('#div_container_sett_acc').replaceWith('<div id="div_container_sett_acc" style="text-align: center;">'+msg+'</div>');

                }
            });
        });   
   });



</script>



                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="true">
                            <li data-theme="c">
                                <a href="#settings" >
                                    Settings
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-theme="c">
                                <a href="#account" id="account_link" >
                                    Account
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div_container_sett_acc">greg</div>


                </div>


<?php

    $pagemaincontent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $pageHead='';

    $home_page='ui-btn-active';
    $pageTitle ='';

    include("master.php");
?>
```

On of the ajax pages being loaded :

```
<?php
include_once ("../includes/mysql.php");
include_once ("../includes/chk.php");
?>





                          <div class="ui-block-b">

                        <div id="settings_link" data-theme="a">

                            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" >   
        <h2>Two</h2>
        <p>I have an id of "two" on my page container. I'm the second page container in this multi-page template.</p>   
        <p>Notice that the theme is different for this page because we've added a few <code>data-theme</code> swatch assigments here to show off how flexible it is. You can add any content or widget to these pages, but we're keeping these simple.</p>  
        <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Back to page "one"</a></p> 

    </div><!-- /content -->


</div><!-- /page two -->

      <div  id="account" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">    
          <form url="">
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                    <label for="textinput1">
                                        Boh
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <label for="selectmenu1">
                                    Choose:
                                </label>
                                <select name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1">
                                    <option value="option1">
                                        Option 1
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                                    <legend>
                                        Choose:
                                    </legend>
                                    <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio1" value="" type="radio" />
                                    <label for="radio1">
                                        Option
                                    </label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                                    <legend>
                                        Choose:
                                    </legend>
                                    <input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
                                    <label for="checkbox1">
                                        Checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->


</div><!-- /page two -->


                    </div>
```

If someone could help me out i would be most great-full

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you're after, but the #account_link and #settings_link run the same bit of code, so it's not going to look like anything changes?

Comment: May be this is what you need but not 100% sure what you want but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794762/jquery-load-is-not-loading-javascript-in-loaded-content/9796012#9796012

Answer (score 0):

You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#account_link').on('click', function() {...})
    $('#settings_link').on('click', function() {...})
});
```

Comment: Do you think this answers the question (although you are correct `.on()` should be used instead of `.bind()` for attaching events using newest versions of jQuery).

Comment: it did not work the jquery code from the other page did not load correctly , but thanks for the tip will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a jquery script code inside loaded content. So, there must be the same in the base page and the same included in code called by `$.post`

$.Posted content is not served by default  `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: so this worked i added the framework jquerymobile files  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script> after i did this it worked fine on the page loaded with ajax but in the original page everything got messed up

Comment: You don't need to include full jquery lib again. What you need is set `$(document).ready`  content again. Your `$('#settings_link')` is in posted file. Then you need to make new `$(document).ready` with action for this href. Better is split actions to functions and then just call this servis function from all files` `$(document).ready`