# jQuery .load() ; calling function in original document

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

On index.html ; an action of the user would trigger a .load() event that load a document generated by php on a div. The loaded document would includes some javascript code. I would want to call the javascript function that is originally defined on index.html. How can it be done? Simply calling the function on the loaded document wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example? It is difficult to understand what you mean - you're loading into a `<div>`, but want to call the function defined at window scope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery .load() is not loading javascript in loaded content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794762/jquery-load-is-not-loading-javascript-in-loaded-content)

Comment: code within AJAX loaded page can call the function that is in main document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the function you want in the callback argument of the load function

```
content.load("../includes/fetch.php",{
                'data':url
            },function(){
               whatever_function();
            }
        );
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -4):

You want all the javascript on the index page, using `.on()`--which deals with present and future. Meaning you can load something into a `div` and have it still work. If you try to have the relevant javascript on the dynamically loaded php it won't work.

Comment: this is making a big assumption that the function has anything to do with events

Comment: -1  last statement about calling code from remote page is simply not true

Comment: I'm speaking from experience.

Comment: something wrrong with your experience then.. can certainly call code from remote page, if it is placed correctly within the html structure. Under certain conditions there are problems, but to state `it won't work` is false

Comment: Good lord, you're taking it so literal. I wasn't trying to be syntactically correct. Stop trolling.

Comment: wow... just pointing out answer is invalid... don't take it so seriously. If you post false information here...expect it to be rebutted as it serves little value

Comment: False information? `Under certain conditions there are problems`...You agreed. I just didn't want to get into detail so I made a general statement.

Comment: it is still false. Why you insist on dragging this out is beyond me. Your attention could be put to better use clarfiying answer with true statements

Comment: Uh, maybe it's because you insult me and (essentially) say I'm lying.

Comment: grow up and use this site properly