# What is an organized way to run js on content load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating an ajax powered webbased application.  I am using jQuery and php. As a temporary solution when $.ajax success callback occurs I load the file.php into the page and on done I run a custom function initialize_js which looks for elements that I know need initialization and runs some javascript for those elements.

My current solution is similiar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796012/1108593)

IMHO, this is going to get quite large and hard to manage.  I know I could separate the js into it's own file and make a 2nd ajax call to load this content as a script but I felt this would have alot of overhead.

What do you recommend so that the code is organized and reusable.  I hope to put my javascirpt_ajax routines into a reusable file for other projects on the site and these customized functions cannot be in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I recomand you to write your javascript code as OOP classes/functions. Google will help you with that.

Then since you said you will have pretty much code, is kinda mandatory to split the JS code in multiple files for multiple reasons: flexibility, maintenance, optimisation etc

In the end you should take a look at[ [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html). It helps you to load js files on the fly. So you load only the functions you need, when you need. Not all the files at the same time.

P.S. IF you want to be more rigorous and work like a pro then you might try an MVC library like BackboneJS, SpineJS, AngularJS etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  These are excelent suggestions.  Due to the time limit of this project (7 weeks from start to finish) I won't be able to do this in the first revision but I will bookmark these suggestions so that on our second or third release we will have things more organized.  Thanks again!